# Creating shared custom-elements within React components

Tags: reactjs, custom-element, micro-frontend

I am taking the approach of wrapping React components into Custom Elements, however I feel it is over-engineering and I can’t really see the benefits.my code looks something like this:

```
<core-app>
    <core-login></core-login>
</core-app>
```

is a Custom Element
 is a Custom Element that renders a React component, this component also contains a mix of some children components like  which are native Custom Elements part of a shared UI Component Library and other React components.

The issue is that I am struggling to make React components to pass props and events to Custom Elements, I managed to parse props into HTML attributes by “stringifying” JSON data.

My concern is that; does all this extra complexity adds any value at all? Wouldn’t I be better if Custom Elements were actually React components?
How do I share common Custom Elements within React components easily?

Answer (score 1):

React is not a technology that plays along with CustomElements and thus WebComponents [very well](https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/).

You should ask yourself, why are you doing this. If you only have React components, converting them into CustomElements just for the sake of it does not give you so much benefit (although it gives you runtime composability for free for the sake of a higher bundle size). You can trivially share (children / UI) React Components between "bigger" (feature) React components.

CustomElements are a [standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html) that is built into all modern browsers and is technology agnostic - React has an own component model that relies on an added *runtime* and is not meant to be easily accessible to other framework technologies. Heavily using React usually means a framework lock in and there are costs associated with that.

Who is controlling the *common CustomElements* that you want to share with React? You? Then ask yourself whether adding a CustomElement wrapper is a benefit at all.

If you are controlling the *common* CustomElements and you **do want** to stick with them, then an alternative to using attributes are [Custom DOM Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events). That way you would not be forced to *serialize* your React props but could dispatch them rather easily.